# Most efficient estimator of mean

Tags: estimation, mse, optimal

Let's say we want to estimate a mean $E[F]$ for some unknown distribution $F$. If we only care about the MSE (and don't mind using biased and non-linear estimator), what theory is available to help us choose the estimator?

For example, given some weak assumptions about $F$, is it possible to find the estimator that, in some sense, not much worse than the best?

My question is motivated by the surprising (to me) observation ([p. 38, Eq. 5.16](http://math.arizona.edu/~faris/stat.pdf)) that it's easy to describe the condition when the sample median is more efficient than the sample mean as an estimator of the population mean.

Comment: The MLE is asymptotically the most efficient estimator, in terms of the variance and is asymptotically unbiased. So for large samples, you your best best is MLE, I think.

Comment: For a better answer than the one in @Greenparker's comment, we really need more information.

Comment: @Greenparker I'd prefer not to rely on asymptotic efficiency, since it really says nothing at all about finite samples. Is there perhaps a reasonably general family of estimators within which (approximately?) best estimators could be identified? Kinda like BLUE, except much less restrictive.

Comment: A common family of estimators is [admissible estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_decision_rule), outside of which you generally never want to look. The other is of course the set of unbiased estimators, but you might not like that answer.

Comment: @Greenparker Yes, knowing admissible estimators would be good. But is there any way to describe them?

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc I meant that we don't know anything about $F$; but if we need to make some weak assumptions about it to be able to say anything useful, then it's ok. I guess I know that $F$ is "not too weird", but I don't know how to define that mathematically.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc "pareto-optimal" means kinda the same as "admissible"? In that, no estimator is better across all possible $F$? In that case, I would imagine there are a huge variety of pareto-optimal predictors, hopefully some of them might be easier to approximate? Also, even if the best known approximation is time consuming, surely some more heuristics are available with lower time complexity?

Comment: Re: Asymptotic against finite sample results. If you look at Corollary 5.1 (p. 37) of the reference you linked to, you will see that the result regarding the variance of the sample median is asymptotic, and so it holds approximately for "large samples". On the other hand the variance of the sample mean is an exact finite sample result.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos thanks, you're right. I guess some asymptotic results provide very decent approximations?